# Object is deinited before flatMap is called

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift

For an example, there is simple task which makes network call and then maps the result.

```
class Task {

    func execute() -> Single<String> {
        return doSomeRequest().flatMap { [weak self] data in
            if let string = self?.map(data: data) {
                return .just(string)
            }
            return .error(Error())
        }
    }

    func doSomeRequest() -> Single<Data> {
        // makes network call and returns Data 
    }

    func map(data: Data) -> String? {
        // maps Data to String 
    }
}
```

And there is function that uses this `Task`:

```
func fetchSomeString() {
    Task().execute().subscribe(onSuccess: { string in
        print(string)
    }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

The problem is that `Task` is deinitialized before even get response from `doSomeRequest()`, due to `weak self` in `flatMap`. One of the solution would be to store Task instance as a property, but let's say there is no place in my case for that.

Is there any solution that doesn't lead to memory leaks in `flatMap`, but executes `Task` properly?

Answer (score 1):

Yes 'one solution is to store `Task` instance as a property' or you can pass/essentially store the instance in your `execute` function.

```
static func execute(_ task: Task) -> Single<String> {
    return task.doSomeRequest().flatMap { data in
        if let string = task.map(data: data) {
            return .just(string)
        }
        return .error(Error())
    }
}
```

Then call it like:

```
Task.execute(Task()).subscri...
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make `map(data:)` be a static method. This way you don't need the `task` instance, and it might make more sense than an instance method if the `map` one doesn't make use of any instance members.

```
class Task {

    func execute() -> Single<String> {
        return doSomeRequest().map { [weak self] data in
            guard let string = Task.map(data: data) else {
                throw Error() 
            }
            return string
        }
    }

    func doSomeRequest() -> Single<Data> {
        // makes network call and returns Data 
    }

    static func map(data: Data) -> String? {
        // maps Data to String 
    }
}
```

I also made some changes to you flow by calling `Single.map` and throwing the error, this is a little more readable.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you simply have to use a strong reference to `self` instead of a weak reference.

I assume that your closure is evaluated once and then discarded. If that is the case, then you will [temporarily have a strong reference cycle that will self-break](https://forums.swift.org/t/retain-cycles-in-closures/6586/5) at the end of the operation.

Comment: What if doSomeRequest won't finish?

Comment: You'll only leak if the closure itself isn't released. It seems to me that your memory graph is `Single<Data> -> closure -> self`, so as long as `Single<Data>` is cleaned up, your `self` will be cleaned up too.

Answer (score 1):

> One of the solution would be to store Task instance as a property, but
>   let's say there is no place in my case for that.

There is one great operator which can store `Task` instance as a property and it doesn't need a place to store it. The operator is called [Using](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/using.html).

Here is a little example:

```
flatMapLatest({ (room: String?) -> Observable<WebSocketServiceValue> in
    switch room {
    case .some(let room):
        return Observable
            .using({ WebSocketServiceInstance(room: room) }, observableFactory: { $0.observable })
    case .none:
        return Observable<WebSocketServiceValue>
            .just(WebSocketServiceValue.connected(false))
    }
})
```

I observer a room which is an optional `String`. If there is a valid room - I create a `WebSocketServiceInstance` and observe its signals. As soon as the room is changed - `WebSocketServiceInstance` is deinited because of `flatMapLatest` operator. So, the instance lives as long as you have a connection.

In your example your `Task` class might live as long as the operation executes if you use `Using` operator. The only thing is required - `Task` class should conform to `Disposable`. But it is very easy:

```
extension WebSocketServiceInstance: Disposable {

    func dispose() {
        socket?.delegate = nil
        socket?.close()
        socket = nil
    }
}
```